# Seaborn countplot with categorical filter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I  have a dataset something like this:

```
ID TAG TYPE
1  A   GT
2  B   NGT
3  C   XT
4  A   NGT
```

I want to plot a graph showing the number of NGT for each tag. How do I achieve this? I could filter by tags and count but I want to do this directly using pandas and/or seaborn/matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean column initially that shows whether `NGT` is `True` or `False`.

```
df["NGT_val"]= df["TYPE"].str.contains("NGT", regex=False)

Output:

    TAG TYPE    NGT
0   A   GT      False
1   B   NGT     True
2   C   XT      False
3   A   NGT     True
```

Then you can do `pd.groupby()`

```
grouped=df.groupby("TAG").agg(num_true=pd.NamedAgg(column="NGT",aggfunc=sum))

Output: # shows the number of "NGT"s present for each TAG.

    num_true
TAG 
A   1
B   1
C   0

# Then plot the chart.I just did the bar plot.
grouped['num_true'].plot(kind="bar")
```